# Disable automatic driver update for only one device in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update, automation

Is there a way we can disable automatic driver update for a specific device in Windows 10? The updated driver for that device (Intel Management Engine Interface 11.x in particular) causes problems on some laptops during. The version 9.x works perfect.

I don't want to disable automatic driver installation for all devices.

Comment: There is a tool for that purpose have you installed it?

Comment: Which tool is it?

Comment: I am honestly too lazy to find the duplicate to this question, if it even exists, so I went ahead and just published an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft published a tool designed to block device driver updates.

Here is the relevant section of that support article:

[image]

The Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package can be downloaded [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/wushowhide.diagcab)

### Source

[How to temporarily prevent a Windows or driver update from reinstalling in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930)