# Windows update not updating drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update

On Windows 10, I have read that all driver updating is done through windows update. Yet if I go into device manager right after running windows update, and check for driver updates, I find that there are some updates that are still available. What am I missing in window update settings to update these?

Comment: Installing device drivers through Windows Update is still an optional setting in Windows 10.  This a personal or corporate computer?

Comment: @Ramhound where is this setting?

Comment: @Moab - [Disable automatic driver update for only one device in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1096937/disable-automatic-driver-update-for-only-one-device-in-windows-10?rq=1).  The differences in the drivers could be explained by the fact, at some point other drivers were installed, device manager lists any drivers for the device.  Windows Update is suppose to only download the current version of those drivers.  More specific information about the drivers would be required to fully explain the behavior.

Comment: That is a "temporary" driver block, more microsoft bullcrap.

Comment: I have this exact problem right now, it happened after upgrading to 1803, no hidden updates but no drivers listed on windows/microsoft update

Answer (score 1):

While Windows Update can pull down generic drivers that will work fine for most users and applications, if you want the latest drivers for your specific hardware, your best bet is to get it from the computer manufacturers website. Also, if you are on a domain environment, there may be group policy in place that is preventing you from pulling down driver updates.

Comment: Does not answer why device manager conflicts with windows updates not finding any driver updates, both use the same service to find driver updates.