# How do I prevent Win10 CREATORS UPDATE from installing drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates

Several years ago when running Win7 Pro on an HP-HDX18t laptop, the hardware vendor produced a defective graphics driver which fried the gpu.  I got around that by disabling the graphics driver and not running any programs that needed it; it's still a pretty fast machine.  I somehow got the laptop to work mostly the same way after up[down]grading to Win10 over a year ago (notably without Bluetooth, either, but that I can ignore), and, after a previous experience with what I am asking about here, turned off "automatically download manufacturers' apps ..."  Until now that setting seemed to prevent Windows Update from touching the graphics driver, but I believe the Creators Update which M$ imposed today ignored it and enabled the gpu anyway:  the machine powers itself down without notice after clicking on NEXT on the new Privacy Settings screen -- the symptom that would result from trying to use the gpu.

I managed to restore Win10 to the previous version, but would like to know how to prevent any possible future M$ updates -- or at least CREATORS UPDATE -- from trying to re-enable, reinstall, or otherwise use the graphics driver.
I was not able to access Safe Mode from Creators Update as it shut down the machine just like the normal mode.

Comment: Take a few minutes to thoroughly read the following tutorial, and it will describe your options:  [Disable Driver Updates in Windows Update in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48277-enable-disable-driver-updates-windows-update-windows-10-a.html).  On the other hand, if you want to be much more specific about blocking that one driver install, reference the following tutorial:  [How to Prevent Windows 10 from Automatically Updating Specific Drivers](https://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable automatic driver update for only one device in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1096937/disable-automatic-driver-update-for-only-one-device-in-windows-10)

Comment: That tutorial only seems to confirm my problem.  I cannot do ANYTHING after the update since the machine shuts down, and the tutorial specifically says that the option I have already used "is no longer available starting with Windows 10 build 15019."  Catch 22.

Comment: You may be able to acquire ISOs of older builds of Windows to boot from and install.  If v1604 worked out for you.

Comment: Yes, but the options that specifically say *"This option is no longer available starting with Windows 10 build 15019"* aren't the only ones within that tutorial.  The other pair will still work on a Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703) machine.

Comment: The "other" options work AFTER Creators Update is installed -- and I repeat yet again, I can do NOTHING with the system after the update. Creators Update is different from all past Win10 updates (which have not been a problem for over a year).  It appears to be Windows 11 without a new moniker.  I have restored my system to its previous version, and presumably can change settings after the update if the gpu is not enabled, but I need some way to prevent Creators Update from installing a graphics driver as part of the update.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like you need to manually initiate the upgrade to version 1703 while the machine is disconnected from the Internet to avoid the GPU driver updates.  After the Creators Update is installed, utilize the "other" options to disable the driver updates, connect the machine to the Internet, and everything should work properly.  Here is a tutorial that helps explain the manual update process:  [How to Download a Windows 10 ISO File](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-download-windows-10-iso-file.html).

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I haven't had time until today -- it's currently crunching on a full system backup before I try anything else.  I'm not quite convinced that an ISO won't have some kind of default driver that could be just as bad.  I read some reports about other graphics problems with the update.  Anyway, I'll let you know.

Comment: Result, after shutdown in the middle of the update:  We couldn't install Windows 10 ... 0xC1900101 - 0x4000D ... The  installation failed in the SECOND_BOOT phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation.  The one nice touch (the very first of any kind since updating to Win10 from Win7) was that it automatically reset the system to its earlier state.

Comment: It sounds like your system is problematic, one way or another.  For future reference, the method I described works:  upgrade your system without an Internet connection, make the changes that you prefer, and then connect the computer to the Internet accordingly.  I have done this successfully on many occasions.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I believe my solution is Linux Mint which I already have installed on another computer.  There appears to be a means of disabling the gpu during installation and there are now Linux versions of all the applications I am concerned about (not true a year ago when I updated from Win7 to Win10).  No doubt some config file will need changing, but I have found good support for that sort of thing in the past.